# Are Haskell data types with only nullary or unary constructors considered as Algebraic Data Types?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

To my limited knowledge Algebraic Data Types in Haskell  can be of two forms namely, sums (e.g. `data Bool = True | False`) or products (e.g. `data Pair = P Int Double`). Below are some data types with nullary and unary value constructors.

```
data Z  = Z
data S n = S n  -- I think that this is a singleton type?
data S = S Int
```

Are these types considered as algebraic data types? If so what are they called?

Comment: A perhaps important correction: ADTs are of *one* form, which is a sum-of-products. `data Bool = True | False` sums two (trivial, one-element) products together, and `data Pair = P Int Double` is a (trivial, one-element) sum containing a single two-element product. Thinking of things this way makes it easier to generalize to more complex types, like `data Working = Known Bool AuditLog | Unknown ErrorCode Explanation`, which is a sum of two two-element products.

Comment: @amalloy Minor correction: your first "trivial, one-element" should be "trivial, no elements" since `True` and `False` take zero arguments.

Comment: @chi I think both are valid ways to describe it, because "element" is a bit fuzzy. It's a product of zero elements, yielding a single element for the sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Z` is just a differently named unit type. A `1` as an ADT. In other words, it is an empty product type. (Likewise, a type with no constructors at all may be considered an empty sum type.)

`S n` is isomorphic to `n` itself. In the framework of ADTs, it is considered *equivalent*, i.e. if `n` is an algebraic type then so is `S n`.

Note however that in Haskell, type definitions are often deliberately treated as opaque, by way of avoiding to export the value constructors. The type is then rather an *abstract* data type instead of an *algebraic* one.